# Vector equation analysis

Tags: vectors, textbook-erratum

Having Problem with the vector equation that i underlined. I want to know how they done the math after the"=". How they done the sum and multiplication

[image: its a picture from text book]

Please check the image. Sorry not for being specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a mistake. The last two expressions should read
$$-\vec{R}\times\vec{Q}=\vec{Q}\times\vec{R}$$

Comment: -(Q+R)XQ= How they came to the result -R+Q. sorry i am using mobole so can not add "→" for all letter.

Comment: It’s a *mistake*.

Answer (score 1):

They used two properties of the vector product, namely

$$\vec{A}\times\vec{A}=0$$

and

$$\vec{A}\times\vec{B}=-\vec{B}\times\vec{A}.$$

(The first is just a special case of the second.)

In addition they used the fact that the vector product *distributes* over vector addition just like ordinary scalar multiplication distributes over ordinary scalar addition:

$$\vec{A}\times(\vec{B}+\vec{C})=\vec{A}\times\vec{B}+\vec{A}\times\vec{C}$$

$$(\vec{A}+\vec{B})\times\vec{C}=\vec{A}\times\vec{C}+\vec{B}\times\vec{C}$$

As the other answer points out, there are also two typos where a $+$ should be a $\times$.

Comment: -(Q+R)XQ= How they came to the result -R+Q. sorry i am using mobole so can not add "→" for all letter.

Comment: MarkH explained that this is a *mistake*. Did you read his answer?

Comment: Oh yes, thanks a lot sir. Really helpful.